# How can I avoid errors with dbms_metadata.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing a custom program to dump the database metadata to files in order to manage them with version control.  The default way that data pump or export works isn't ideal for a few reasons (eg. I'd like a separate directory per table).

Sql Developer provides a number of ways of creating export scripts for any object.  One way is just by right-clicking the object and selecting `Quick DDL`.  By viewing the logs it creates, one can see the actual SQL it issues to create the DDL script.  I've used these scripts to write my custom program and for the most part, they've been perfect.

When I generate the DDL for a materialized view, the SQL it generates is:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('MATERIALIZED_VIEW',:name,:owner) FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL('INDEX',TABLE_NAME, TABLE_OWNER) FROM (
    SELECT table_name, table_owner FROM all_indexes 
    WHERE table_owner = :owner AND table_name = :name 
    AND index_name NOT IN (
        SELECT constraint_name FROM sys.all_constraints 
        WHERE table_name = table_name AND constraint_type = 'P'
    ) AND ROWNUM = 1
) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT dbms_metadata.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL ('COMMENT', :name,:owner ) FROM DUAL
```

For this script, when executed via SQL Developer `Quick DDL`, it generates the metadata for the materialized view properly.  When I run this script in a program (or even manually with SQL Developer itself), it produces the following errors:

```
ORA-31608: specified object of type COMMENT not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8436
ORA-06512: at line 1
31608. 00000 -  "specified object of type %s not found"
*Cause:    The specified object was not found in the database.
*Action:   Correct the object specification and try the call again.
```

This particular materialized view doesn't have any comments (obviously), but I would have expected this part of the clause to just return 0 rows instead of generating an error (especially since SQL Developer uses this itself seemingly without errors).

**Is there a way I can avoid this error, while still including comments in the metadata if they exist?**

This issue exists on both Oracle 10g & 11g databases.

Comment: Maybe problem is with grant. check which grants you have given to your user

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana: Problem isn't with grants.  Same user in Sql Developer, and this succeeds when there are comments.

Comment: you mean it happens just when there is no comment?

Comment: @Saeidsamadidana: correct.

Comment: How did you create a materialized view without comment? I tried and it always creates me some dummy comment.. And dropping by setting comment to '' does not remove it.

Comment: @dcieslak:  `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mview
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FAST
START WITH SYSDATE + 2/(24*60)
NEXT SYSDATE + 60/(24*60*60)
WITH PRIMARY KEY 
AS SELECT * FROM some_table;` creates a materialized view (without a comment) in 10g for me.  I agree though that setting the comment to '' after does not delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to test as I don't really know how to create `mview` without `comment`... However the below should work for you. Try to query `dba_mview_comments` instead of `dual` to not execute the function when you don't have comments.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl ('COMMENT', :name, :owner)
  FROM dba_mview_comments mvc
 WHERE mvc.mview_name = :name AND
   mvc.owner = :owner AND
   length(comments) > 0 AND
   rownum = 1
```

Comment: I get the same error here.  There is a record with a `null` comment in dba_mview_comments, even though I did not add a comment on the table.  If I specifically add a comment of `''` on the table, then I don't get my original error (or one here).  There must be some other table it is querying when it runs the `dba_metadata.get_dependent_ddl`.  (or maybe just some sort of bug in the `get_dependent_ddl` procedure).

Comment: Modify my query with additional `length(comments) > 0` and it should work. The main idea is to not call the function when it's not necessary.

Comment: Works, thanks.  
Still wish I knew: a) how this appears to work via `Quick DDL`, but not through sqlplus, and
b) what the difference between a comment of `''`, and never having created a comment to begin with